# how to recover blog

Tags: data-recovery, cache, blogging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recovering a lost website with no backup?](https://superuser.com/questions/82036/recovering-a-lost-website-with-no-backup)

I had my blog at someURL.me ,

I don't know the service provider,host,or anything

It is now suspended for some reason (its not like illegal thing).

How can i recover data?

Can I use google cached to retrieve I don't know its not in search result even

Or is there any way out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume your blog url was http://blogurl.com/
The google cache url for this will be **http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:blogurl.com/**

Examples of websites and their google cache urls:

1. Fark (http://www.fark.com/) : 
   http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:www.fark.com/
2. SuperUser (https://superuser.com/) : http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:superuser.com/

Unfortunately if you don't remember the url to your blog you are out of luck.

You can also try WayBackMachine: [Link](http://www.archive.org/web/web.php)

Good Luck!